# Update inner array in multiple array document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying this question... I don't want use the "_id" : "12", field..

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62622dd73905f04f59db2971"),
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "12",
            "array2" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : "123",
                    "answeredBy" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : "124",
                    "answeredBy" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to update using the following query

```
db.getCollection('nestedArray').updateMany(
 {'array1.array2._id':'123'},
 {$push:{'array1.array2.$[inner].answeredBy':'success'}},
 {arrayFilters:[{'inner._id':'123'}]}
)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> "errmsg" : "The path 'array1.array2' must exist in the document in
> order to apply array updates.",

I just trying to understand what is wrong with the code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `$[]` between array1 and array2

[Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----)

```
db.collection.update({
  "array1.array2._id": "123"
},
{
  $push: {
    "array1.$[].array2.$[inner].answeredBy": "success"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "inner._id": "123"
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bfRinTy4LJ1)

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan I update my answer with an official reference